# Auto-response email when a case is created

Tags: case-auto-response

I am implementing a flow on Salesforce where I have enabled email-to-case to register emails coming as case. I will have to notify the customer who is sending the email to our support email that the request is received and would require further information to proceed.

Comment: What is your question?  Please [edit] your post to describe the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly then the solution is quite simple. Please go to Setup and in the Quickfind box enter "Case Auto-Response Rule." There you can create an acknowledgement mail for email2case. Rest of the part is pretty simple and I am sure you will be able to figure it out one you explore this path.

Comment: I need to send the ack email + in the same email I need to request for further details from customer. Basically the email should go from support email for which customer initially had sent the query. Can workflow email action do this or should i use a process builder